# Private package, wrong URL

Tags: npm

My `.npmrc` file:

```
@mylib:registry=https://npm.site.com
```

When trying to install @mylib I have the following error:

```
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://npm.site.com/https://npm.site.com/@mylib%2fshared-lib/-/shared-lib-1.0.12.tgz
```

I can download file by `https://npm.site.com/@mylib%2fshared-lib/-/shared-lib-1.0.12.tgz` but looks like `npm` is trying to get it by wrong URL by duplicating the path

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with wrong `url_prefix` in `Verdaccio` config file

Comment: Depends of the verdaccio version you were using configuration might be diferent, you can read https://verdaccio.org/blog/2021/04/14/verdaccio-5-migration-guide#url_prefix-improved-behavior